# MySQL Cross Linked Join For Records Without Current Payments

Tags: mysql, sql

Background:
Table members has fields like lastname, firstname, member_id (key auto inc column)
Table paid has fields like year, member_id (pointer to the members.member_id column)

Target:
Create a query to pull all lastname, firstname and member_id from the members table which don't have current payment records.

I've tried from other responses here I've checked just for something to start with:

```
SELECT DISTINCT lname, fname, suffix, members.member_id, MaxDateTime
FROM members
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT paid.member_id, MAX(paid.year) AS MaxDateTime
    FROM paid
    GROUP BY paid.member_id) groupedpaid 
ON members.member_id = groupedpaid.member_id
```

This seems to get the maximum paid date for each member. How this works when the previous example still had another AND clause as below I don't understand. The example I found on stackoverflow had the following line:

```
AND groupedpaid.paid = MaxDateTime
```

If a member has a paid date of 2016-12-31 I want to find all the members which have payment dates less than this date. I figured if I could find the maximum payment record date I then could do something like Where paid.year < '2016-12-31' on the final statement.

TIA.

Comment: Always qualify your column names (that is, use table aliases).  Then you will never have this problem.  In addition, never use commas in the `from` clause; always use explicit `join` syntax.

Comment: what do you mean with "whitout Current Payments"  .. if you explain better because ai don't understand your question ..